# When I start my app with PM2 + Docker, just run and exit

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, pm2

I try to follow [this tutorial](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/docker-pm2-nodejs/), but when I execute my app nothing happens

My Dockerfile (CHANGED)

```
FROM keymetrics/pm2-docker-alpine:7

WORKDIR /api

RUN npm install pm2 -g

ADD . .

CMD ["pm2-docker", "ecosystem.config.js"]
```

And my `ecosystem.config.js`..

```
const maxMemory = process.env.WEB_MEMORY || 80;
const nodeEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'api',
      script: 'api/index.js',
      node_args: [
        '--optimize_for_size', '--max_old_space_size=400', '--gc_interval=100',
      ],
      instances: process.env.WEB_CONCURRENCY || -1,
      exec_mode: 'cluster',
      max_memory_restart: `${maxMemory}M`,
      env: {
        PORT: process.env.PORT || 3000,
        NODE_ENV: nodeEnv,
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

After run the docker ..

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --name api api:latest
```

Nothing happens.. follow the result of `docker ps -a`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                           COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                      NAMES
167cb2769438        api:latest   "pm2-docker start ..."   50 seconds ago      Exited (1) 47 seconds ago
```

### ADDED

If I run without `-d` option ..

```
> docker run -it -p 3000:3000 --name api api:latest
module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'commander'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/CLI/RuntimeCLI.js:4:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
[vagrant@localhost]$
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Your code does not match the documentation that you linked.

Comment: @jww and about pm2 ? This question is specific for Docker+Pm2. And pm2 is an developer tool. Is about run Node+Pm2 in Docker. So I think the best place is here insted  [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange ](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @BurhanKhalid why not?

Comment: @jww can you please kindly explain why this question  `is not about programming or development`?

Comment: You should ask questions about your favorite VM on [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @jww this is not about my favorite VM.. is about run **Node+Pm2** in Docker.

Comment: @ridermansb have you created the process.yml that the docs says? Also, you don't need to explicitly install pm2

Comment: @Robert yes.. I also try to change `CMD ["pm2-docker", "ecosystem.config.js"]` but same result

Comment: @Robert, maybe because I need to copy my app to the docker image..as I ask here.. https://hashnode.com/post/how-to-copy-files-and-execute-pm2-with-docker-cj3z73i9i00cfr7k82m0o07aj?notifyPrompt=true

Comment: I can't any place where you put your app inside the container. Remove the `-d` in docker run command, in order to see the output

Comment: Do this to inspect the content of your image: `docker run -it api sh`

Comment: @Robert .. I add the output

Comment: Remove the RUN npm install pm2 -g, because PM2 is already bundled into pm2-docker-alpine

Comment: @Unitech Thanks. It works.

Comment: Great just made an official answer on this question

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `RUN npm install pm2 -g`, because PM2 is already bundled into pm2-docker-alpine